# (!IE) Problems with Blocking Code from IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I have (once again) been enhancing my template for a school site. However, I have run into another problem. I have noticed that the navigation bar does not render properly in any Internet Explorer version prior to IE9 (to be expected). I had seen the use of the !IE tag around the web and tried replicating it on my design. However, once implemented, every browser stopped showing that piece of code.

```
<!--[if !IE]>
    <li><p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></li>
    <li><img src="vp-global-logo.gif" />
<![endif]-->
```

I also tried:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
    <li><p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></li>
    <li><img src="vp-global-logo.gif" />
<![endif]-->
```

How would I get this to work? Is there any alternative method without making the site too slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to terminate the conditional comments with a special syntax:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <li><p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></li>
    <li><img src="vp-global-logo.gif" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

This prevents IE from displaying the HTML while other browsers get to see it, treating the if and else as regular HTML comments.

Answer (score 1):

You're commenting out the list items, try changing your code to this:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]--><!-->
    <li><p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p></li>
    <li><img src="vp-global-logo.gif" />
<!--><![endif]-->
```